# Cannot read property '$owl' of undefined in angular 8 OwlCarousel

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In typescript file

```
 export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('owlCarousel', { static: false }) owlElement: OwlCarousel;

  displayDetail(currentDetail: PageData) {
    this.owlElement.to([selectIndex]);
  }
}
```

In html page:

```
<owl-carousel [options]="carousel1ItemOption" class="detail-page" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'sliding']" [items]="records" #detailOwlCarousel>
    <section class="item" *ngFor="let detailPageData of records">
      <h1 class="titleHead mb-2">{{detailPageData.title | titleString}}</h1>
    </section>
  </owl-carousel>
```

Comment: please explain what are you trying to do and where are you facing the error

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes then please inform me .I have same issue. I have passed same name in @viewChild

Answer (score 0):

Change  `#detailOwlCarousel` for `#owlCarousel`. The name you passed in the `@ViewChild` annotation has to match.